# Flexible Selection In Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following lines of code:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Counterparty':['Bank','Client','GSE','PSE'],
                'Maturity':[2, 3, 2, 2],
                'Amount':[50, 55, 65, 55],
                'Match':[0,0,0,0]})

CounterpartyList=['Bank','Client']
MaturityList=[2,3]

df1.loc[(df1['Counterparty'].isin (CounterpartyList))& (df1['Maturity'].isin (MaturityList)),'Match']=420
```

If either of the two lists ( CounterpartyList or MaturityList) have a '#' in them I want the code to behave as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Counterparty':['Bank','Client','GSE','PSE'],
                'Maturity':[2, 3, 2, 2],
                'Amount':[50, 55, 65, 55],
                'Match':[0,0,0,0]})

CounterpartyList=['Bank','Client']  
MaturityList=['#']

df1.loc[(df1['Counterparty'].isin(CounterpartyList)) ,'Match']=420
```

i.e.. I ignore the condition for matching MaturityList or CounterpartyList when they contain a #.

Any ideas for the most efficient way to do this ? I have quite a lot of conditions, so want to avoid a large CASE condition

Comment: What if both `CounterpartyList` and `MaturityList` contain `#`?

Comment: then 'Match' will be populated for all rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to create a bollean mask for each of the lists and then intersect them

```
>> bm1 = ('#' in CounterpartyList) | df1['Counterparty'].isin(CounterpartyList)
>> bm2 = ('#' in MaturityList) | df1['Maturity'].isin(MaturityList)
>> df1.loc[bm1 & bm2, 'Match'] = 420
>> df1
   Amount Counterparty  Match  Maturity
0      50         Bank    420         2
1      55       Client    420         3
2      65          GSE      0         2
3      55          PSE      0         2
```